# crashing generating fire-balls(bullets) with Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I got crash, making fire-balls as bullets.

I guess I should not use   "private Array fireballs" in player class.
it seems like when I add one more fire as index of 1 into the list, the first index does not look working on destroying in for loop in player class. 
it seems only destrying index of 0.

in playscreen class,

```
 public void handleInput(float dt){
       if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
            playerBlue.fire();
        }
```

in player class,

```
private Array<FireBall> fireballs;
public void update(float dt) {
  for (FireBall ball : fireballs) {
        ball.update(dt);
        if (ball.isDestroyed())
            fireballs.removeValue(ball, true);
    }   

 }
public void fire() {
    fireballs.add(new FireBall(screen, b2body.getPosition().x, b2body.getPosition().y, Blue.runRightSide ? true : false));

}
```

in fire class,

```
public class FireBall extends Weapon {
private TextureRegion fireball;
private float rotate;
public FireBall(PlayScreen screen, float x, float y, boolean rightside) {
    super(screen, x, y, rightside);
    fireball = new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("fireball"),0,0,40,40);
    setRegion(fireball);
    setBounds(getX(),getY(),getWidth()*2,getHeight()*2);

}

@Override
protected void defineWeapon() {
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(rightside ? getX() + 12 / AlienAdvantrue.PPM : getX() - 12 / AlienAdvantrue.PPM, getY());
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    if (!world.isLocked())
        body = world.createBody(bdef);//?
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(3 / AlienAdvantrue.PPM);
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = AlienAdvantrue.FIREBALL_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = AlienAdvantrue.GROUND_BIT
            |AlienAdvantrue.Enemy_Head_BIT
            |AlienAdvantrue.BRICK_BIT
            |AlienAdvantrue.COIN_BIT
            |AlienAdvantrue.Enemy_BIT;


    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.restitution = 1;
    fdef.friction = 0;
    body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(rightside ? 2 : -2, 2.5f));
    body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this); 

}

public void update(float dt){
    stateTime += dt;
    rotate +=100; // flip faste// ?
    rotate(rotate);
    setPosition(body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);

    if((stateTime > 3 || setToDestroy) && !destroyed) {
        world.destroyBody(body);
        destroyed = true;
        stateTime=0;
    }
    if(body.getLinearVelocity().y > 2f)
        body.setLinearVelocity(body.getLinearVelocity().x, 2f);
    if((rightside && body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0) || (!rightside && body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0))
        setToDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably this loop:

```
  for (FireBall ball : fireballs) {
        ball.update(dt);
        if (ball.isDestroyed())
            fireballs.removeValue(ball, true);
    }
```

you're removing items while iterating on your loop. That plays funny with the internal iterator since the size of `fireball` changes: items are basically skipped, and other strange effects.

I'm not an expert, but what's recommended in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java) is to handle the iterator manually:

```
public void update(float dt) {

for(Iterator<FireBall> i = fireballs.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
       Fireball ball = i.next();           
        if (ball.isDestroyed())
          i.remove()
 }
```